# sockets - only receiving errors after attempting send

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, connection

I have a TCP server with code that looks like this (in a loop):

```
r, w, e = select([self.sock], [self.sock], [self.sock], 0)
if r or e:
    try:
        data = self.sock.recv(2048)
    except:
        debug("%s: .recv() crashed!"%self.id)
        debug(traceback.format_exc())
        break
```

For some reason, my connection from the client to this server randomly breaks, but I only see that it broke once I try to send data, then I get the error from recv(), is there any way to detect the error without trying to send data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the connection was closed, you may not know it's closed until you attempt a send.  By default, TCP won't automatically detect if the remote machine disappears without sending a disconnect.

What you're seeing is the correct behavior and something you need to handle.  Make sure you don't assume that all exceptions from recv are "crashes", though.  I don't know python, but there are likely different exceptions (including disconnects) that you need to handle but the code you posted doesn't deal with properly.

You should either enable TCP keepalive or send application-layer no-op packets to determine if your connection is still open.

Comment: May I ask why I can't check for errors without sending? Is it because the TCP stack doesn't know the connection died until I try to send something and the other end sends back an error?

Comment: Exactly.  There isn't some sort of physical link connecting the two.  The "connection" is simply two sides sending packets and agreeing that they are connected.  It can't somehow know that the other side has gone away until either a connection close has been negotiated, a timeout has been reached or it's attempted to send data and been rejected by the other side.  Basically imagine the other side of the connection lost power.  It can't send a message that it went away, so your process has to determine that somehow.  Trying to send is how it figures that out.

Comment: Also, it's not an "error", it's just disconnected.  How would you imagine you would check for the error -- you'd have to send a packet to the other system and see if you got a proper response.  Well, that's what send does.

Comment: Okay, so the preferred method would be to just send keep alive packets to make sure the connection is alive?

Comment: Not usually, no.  What's wrong with the current behavior?  TCP will notify you eventually that the other side is gone via a read notification in your select.  It's just if you try to send before then, you'll get an econnreset on send and then you'll get the read notification that the connection has been terminated.

Comment: The code is for a python p2p library, each "client" keeps a persistent TCP connection to the server for connection negotiation (hole punching etc), the client has code to reconnect if the connection fails. Unfortunately sometimes A tries to connect to B, but the server doesn't realize B's connection to the server died till it tries to send something (like a "connection" request). Meanwhile, B never tried to send anything (because it never got anything) so it never notices it disconnected and never tries to reconnect. So reaching B is now impossible, unless B sends something on his end.

Comment: So the connection is never silently lost to both sides.  Either one side had the OS suddenly end or at least one side knows the connection is gone.  That one can be responsible for re-establishing the connection.

Comment: A and B are behind NATs rendering direct connection from the server impossible, thus why a negotiation server is necessary so it can hole punch from A to B.

Comment: Remember, the OS is responsible for the TCP connections.  If a process ends, the OS will initiate the TCP disconnect process, and you will get a notification of disconnect via a readable filehandle in your select.  Only if the remote machine crashes hard or loses power will you lose your connection without being notified immediately.  Or, if you network is flaky, I suppose.

Comment: NAT has nothing to do with this.  TCP only connects two hosts, not 3.  I understand the server cannot reconnect.  If the connection is lost, your client will eventually be notified that the connection is gone and can attempt to re-establish the connection.  If it has to be "fast", then yes, I suppose you may want to send keep-alives of some sort.  Read this: http://www.hep.by/gnu/linux/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Comment: I was referencing the NAT because it makes it so the server can't reconnect. The client never really sends anything to the server, because the pseudo-connection process starts from a packet it got from the server. The error I'm getting is either "Connection reset by peer", or "Connection aborted by software in the machine". The client may eventually realize, but it would be too late, too many people may fail to connect to him by then.

Comment: @FaultException so, with all that said, it sounds like you do want to set up keepalives, either with the TCP option or at the application layer.